# Array out of bound exception while deleting certain information from a String

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, replace

I have an `ArrayList` that contain `String`. I want to loop through this `ArrayList`, get all `String` and find if they contain a certain set of character and then erase it.

Example of what i mean : in the `String` "Hi, my name is Bobby" I want to remove "Hi, my name is " and just keep "Bobby".

Here is my function :

```
private ArrayList<String> epurateInformation(ArrayList<String> list) {
    String[] potentialThreat = {"Pret : ", "Nom de l'Album : ", "Style : ", "Date : ", "Nom de la piste : ", "Propriétaire : ", "Information : "};

    for(String s : list) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= potentialThreat.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(potentialThreat[i]);
            //The error is right below here
            if(s.contains(potentialThreat[i])) {
                s.replace(potentialThreat[i], "");
            }
            cdInformation.add(s);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

It gives me a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I tried to replace **potentialThreat.length** to a fixed `int`(by 7, 6 and 1), but it still give me this error.

If you need more info let me know. If you have another idea on how to run that also let me know. thanks

Comment: What's the highest value that `i` gets in your program? What's the highest valid index of an element in `potentialThreat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are zero based, you need < not <= so:

```
private ArrayList<String> epurateInformation(ArrayList<String> list) {
    String[] potentialThreat = {"Pret : ", "Nom de l'Album : ", "Style : ", "Date : ", "Nom de la piste : ", "Propriétaire : ", "Information : "};

    for(String s : list) {
        for(int i = 0; i < potentialThreat.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(potentialThreat[i]);
            //The error is right below here
            if(s.contains(potentialThreat[i])) {
                s.replace(potentialThreat[i], "");
            }
            cdInformation.add(s);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: How did i not saw this? Anyway thanks. I'll mark your answer as **THE** answer when SO will allow me